# two MPPT tracker on the same solar panel string?

Tags: solar-cell, mppt

I would like to know if possible to use two distinct MPPT on the same solar panel string.

Comment: I forsee regulation problems.

Comment: It's on the DC side so normally no big issue IMHO

Comment: @winny There's a lot of information lacking, s/he never says he will put the output together, or not. If s/he would put them in parallel then you'd be correct. But since hotips needs to learn how to make a question, we won't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess yes, depending on which trackers you use, but this is probably not a recommended mode of operation. From the point of view of the solar panels, you can think of an MPPT as a variable resistor which sets its load to whatever gives the highest amount of power. In theory, having two of them is just like having two variable resistors in parallel. If everything works properly, each one will get half the power (and the resistances will be double).

However, the problem comes when you take the feedback into account. MPPT's use a variety of different algorithms to get the right "resistance" value. There could be modes where the MPPT's are "fighting" each other, resulting in improper power point tracking or even undefined operation. Unless you can find a MPPT that's designed to work with other MPPTs, I would probably avoid it. Why do you need this anyway?

also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It's pretty silly this days to convert everything to AC as many of the products in the house are using DC power supplies. Why not having the string inverter as usual and a DC-DC to charge a battery to supply some DC equipments in parallel ?

Comment: Well maybe, but it gets complicated if you start using multiple voltages. You might be able to have a single high dc voltage (high because otherwise you start getting significant resistive loss) that you then downconvert later, but there may be unforseen risks of using dc distribution vs ac.

Comment: @hotips Nikola Tesla wanted mains electricity to be AC, Edison wanted mains electricity to be DC. [Tesla won](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyQfrzBfnDU), guess why. Nowadays we can use HVDC which is a little bit better than HVAC.